# LWUIT + Nokia SDK 2.0 Form turning black, when swiped on screen

Tags: lwuit-form

I'm having a strange problem with the Form of LWUIT. I am making a simple game, which you can control with the touchscreen. I just want to use simple touch events, no swipes. However, when  a swipe event happens, the screen turns fully black. After some normal touch events, the picture comes back, but this is really annoying. Which property of the Form do I have to set, that this doesn't happen?
The problem does also occur on the phone itself, not only on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I had to **override** the **public void pointerDragged(int x, int y)** method inside my form (empty body).